# Pixi.JS Collision detection

Tags: javascript, game-development, pixi.js

I am making a 2D game in Pixi.JS and electron.

Here is my game.js:

```js
const {Application, Graphics} = require("pixi.js")

import {Player} from "./src/player/player.js"

const app = new Application()


window.onload = initGame

async function initGame() {
    await app.init({background: '#1099bb',resizeTo:window});
    app.canvas.style.position = "absolute"
    app.canvas.style.top = "0px"
    app.canvas.style.left = "0px"

    document.body.appendChild(app.canvas)

    gameLogic()
}

async function gameLogic() {

    const player = new Player("Player", app)

    globalThis.objects = []

    const platform = new Graphics()

    platform.rect(0,0,150,600)
    platform.fill(0x0000FF)

    platform.x = app.screen.width / 2;
    platform.y = app.screen.height / 2 + 100;

    app.stage.addChild(platform)
    objects.push(platform)


    //Update
    app.ticker.add(gameLoop)
    app.ticker.add(()=> {player.update(app,globalThis.objects)})
    app.ticker.add(() => {console.log(player.isTouching(platform))})
}

async function gameLoop(delta) {
}
```

And here is my src/player/player.js:

```js
const {Graphics} = require("pixi.js")

class Player {
    constructor(name,app) {
        this.player = new Graphics();

        this.player.rect(0,0,128,64)
        this.player.fill(0xFFFFFF)

        this.player.x = app.screen.width / 2;
        this.player.y = app.screen.height / 2 - 100;

        app.stage.addChild(this.player)

        document.addEventListener("keydown", (ev) => {
            if (ev.keyCode == 68) {
                this.player.x += 1;
            } else if (ev.keyCode == 65) {
                this.player.x -= 1;
            }
        })
    }
    update(app, delta) {
        app.stage.position.set(app.renderer.screen.width / 2, app.renderer.screen.height / 2);
        app.stage.pivot.set(this.player.x + 64, this.player.y + 32);
    
        globalThis.objects.forEach((Obj) => {
            if (!this.isTouching(Obj)) {
                this.player.y += 1;
            }
        })
    }


    isIn(object) {
        const playerBound = this.player.getBounds()
        const objectBound = object.getBounds()

        return(
            playerBound.x < objectBound.x + objectBound.width
            && playerBound.x + playerBound.width > objectBound.x
            && playerBound.y < objectBound.y + objectBound.height
            && playerBound.y + playerBound.height > objectBound.y
        )
    }
    isTouching(object) {
        const playerBound = this.player.getBounds();
        const objectBound = object.getBounds();

        return (
            playerBound.x <= objectBound.x + objectBound.width &&
            playerBound.x + playerBound.width >= objectBound.x &&
            playerBound.y <= objectBound.y + objectBound.height &&
            playerBound.y + playerBound.height >= objectBound.y
        );
    }
    
}

export {Player}
```

The problem is that in my `update` function, it watch if the player is touching all the platforms of the game, but don't check if it is touching from up,down,left,right. How can split the `isTouching` function into four functions:

isUpTouching,
isDownTouching,
isLeftTouching,
isRightTouching.

Some AI give me that code:

```js
isYTouching(object) {

  const playerBound = this.player.getBounds();

  const objectBound = object.getBounds();


  return (

    playerBound.y <= objectBound.y + objectBound.height &&

    playerBound.y + playerBound.height >= objectBound.y

  );

}
```

It returns me false, when the player touches once the platform it returns me true, and returns me true when the player don't touch the platform after touching once.

I think it because it detect only the Y, and not X, so it doesn't check the width of the player and the platform.

Comment: You could create four hitboxes in the player (up, left, down, bottom). Depending on what hitbox detects a collision, you know on what side the player hit something.

Comment: I will try...I think I will do parts of my character, like head, feet and body